# USB hard drive enclosure presents 4K sector disk as having 512B sectors

Tags: arch-linux, lvm

When my server's CPU called it quits, I stuck its SSD in my laptop and hastily ran to Fry's to pick up some USB 3.0 HDD enclosures to spin up my 5-drive LVM RAID array.  When I got back, I hooked everything up, hit the power button, and watched it boot to a rescue prompt.  After some investigating, I found the problem.

My server's motherboard chipset  correctly presented the drives as having 4096-byte sectors, and `fdisk` happily formatted them as such.  I created some PVs, spun up a RAID5 array, and didn't think any more of it.  The USB 3.0 HDD enclosures I got appear to present these 4096-byte sector drives as having 512-byte sectors.  The partition tables are perfectly legible, and it's detecting the PVs just fine, but LVM is having *none* of it.  It noticed that the sector count of the drives was eight times larger than the sector count it had cached and was expecting, and thus refused to assemble the VG.

My question is this: is there a way, either by doing something heinous involving firmware to the enclosures themselves, or by doing something heinous to the kernel to convince it to emulate 4096 byte sectors when they're really 512, to convince LVM to work?

All five drives are 4TB and, strangely enough, the enclosures report them as such -- there is no sign of the infamous over-2TB bug.  It just presents the 4096-byte-sector disk as having 512-byte sectors, and makes up the difference by presenting 8 times as many sectors.

Comment: If you switch drives between enclosure and internal regularly, getting a different enclosure is the only sane option (no idea if they have hackable firmwares and that would depend on the exact model/chipset I guess). Usually it's the partition table itself that refuses to cooperate (even GPT still depends on physical sector size). LVM being the problem is new to me and I would like to know more about it, any chance you can share LVM metadata, like a `vgcfgdump` or commands to reproduce? Also the exact error messages it prints for you?

Comment: As for emulating 4096-sector disk, `losetup` has `--sector-size` option.

Comment: I think this is done because USB has an optimal packet size ... but anyway it's common.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of the USB-to-ATA bridge in the USB enclosured. I am affected by the same bug, my bridge chip is by JMicron (and if you google for that manufacturer, you'll find other people affected by it).

I looked into to it when I first noticed it, and IIRC, the problem is that the SCSI protocol has the information about the physical vs. logical size in some of the later fields in the response to the command that inquires for it, and the bridge firmware probably has some length constant for that response that's too low and doesn't transfer that field.

At that time I also tried to find a way to just tell the kernel directly about the physical sector size and override the wrong information, but couldn't find one. Maybe that has changed in the meantime.

If the data is important, get some enclosures with a bridge chip without the bug.

Comment: As already hinted in the comments above, loop devices may come save the day, but I think it's important to distinguish between bugs and "outright limitations". The former usually just require a little bit [more](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.9/drivers/usb/storage/unusual_uas.h) [carefulness](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.9/drivers/usb/storage/unusual_devs.h) and could be even fixed with a firmware update (JMicron USB3 chips have many). The later are almost a [lost cause](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306857/536967) and if it's even possible will require some very wack kluge.